# First tomcat application - 'ant install' error "NoClassDefFound"

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, ant

JSP/servlets are something I would like to learn, so I set about creating my first tomcat application.

I have gone through the apache tutorial [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/index.html), and progressed to trying to install my application in tomcat (simple test html file with appropriate dir structure). Now, I realise its very wishful thinking hoping to use the [stock](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/build.xml.txt) build.xml provided by the tutorial but I need to start somewhere, Im not sure how to write one myself just yet. I have looked for examples, but they dont seem to have 'install' targets, perhaps they are not web applications.

My project builds, but does not install onto tomcat via ant. When I attempt to 'ant install' my console outputs...

```
 ant install
Buildfile: /home/mark/svn/tomcatapp/build.xml
Trying to override old definition of datatype resources

prepare:

compile:
    [javac] /home/mark/svn/tomcatapp/build.xml:299: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds

install:

BUILD FAILED
/home/mark/svn/tomcatapp/build.xml:375: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/util/buf/B2CConverter
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Base64.encode(Base64.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.ant.AbstractCatalinaTask.execute(AbstractCatalinaTask.java:204)
    at org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask.execute(DeployTask.java:211)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:811)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.B2CConverter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 19 more

Total time: 0 seconds
```

Why would a class fail to be found, would it not be contained within the tomcat install? There is a similar question, but I am not attempting to use the manager app, and I am not sure how to edit the class path - would I need to have compiled a .java class to create one for the project?

I am sure a more simple build file would suffice, but I am not sure which components are relevant. Sorry for the potentially very stupid questions.

Here is my install target from my build.xml file.

```
  <target name="install" depends="compile"
   description="Install application to servlet container">

    <deploy url="${manager.url}"
       username="${manager.username}"
       password="${manager.password}"
           path="${app.path}"
       localWar="file://${build.home}"/>

  </target>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the sample build.xml , change

```
localWar="file://${build.home}"
```

to

```
war="${dist.home}/${app.name}-${app.version}.war"
```

If you have catalina-ant.jar in ANT_HOME/lib. Try removing it from this location.

Restart tomcat.

That has worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

- copy file tomcat-util.jar from `CATALINA_HOME/lib` to `ANT_HOME/lib` **OR**
- when issuing ant commands, add `-lib` option with a path to that file,
  for example 
   `ant -lib C:\Tomcat8\lib\tomcat-util.jar install` 
   (provided `CATALINA_HOME` points to `C:\Tomcat8`)

**Explanation:**

I have encountered similar problem with Tomcat 8.0.36. According to error message class `org.apache.tomcat.util.codec.binary.Base64` was not found. *ant install* command from the tutorial executes *deploy* task, that is not a standard task in Ant, but a custom task provided by Tomcat. Deploy task is implemented by `DeployTask` class (full name of the class is `org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask`) which is placed in `CATALINA_HOME/lib/catalina-ant.jar`. Custom tasks (like `DeployTask`) usually are dependent on external libraries, so you need to add those libraries to Ant's classpath. For more information see [Optional Tasks in Ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#optionalTasks).

Answer (score 0):

You have hit https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52148

Upgrade to the latest Tomcat 7 release and the problem will go away.

Comment: I am running the latest version I think, Downloaded 7.0.29 two days ago. How would I go about editing the classpath to apply the solution listed on that page. I cant seem to find catalina-task.xml. Thanks.

Comment: That file is in $CATALINA_HOME/bin

Comment: Thank you, found it and discovered the fix was already implemented as I imagined for the latest version. If I discover the problem I will post.

Answer (score 0):

I am also running a new version of Tomcat (7.0.32) and encountered the same error while trying to follow the tutorial. I know this isn't the best solution, but perhaps it will be helpful in your debugging: When I use the `-lib` option with `ant` I was able to make it pull in the jar files with the needed classes:
`ant -lib /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.32/lib/ -lib /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.32/bin/ install` (In my case `/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.32` is `$CATALINA_HOME`)